# '@media' doesn't affect my Jumbotron header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Hello I've just started web development a few days ago.
I want my web page's header to be responsive so its width, height, font-size be flexible.

```
<header class="text-white">
<div class="jumbotron bgimg text-white">
  <h1 class="display-4">    
    <i class="fa fas fa-star"></i>
    Hello, World!<i class="fa fas fa-star fa-1x"></i></h1>
  <p class="lead">This is my webpage</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p class="lead">Web page details.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="./file.zip" download="" role="button">Download!</a>
</div>
```

So I wrote the code like this so that my letter size will be printed small on a small mobile device. My problem is it stays the same and my background image randomly cropped. 
Is it because I set `display-4` on `h1`?

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #headerh1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Thank you, for always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with selector simple Use

```
h1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Or

```
h1.display-4{
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
```

or more precisely

```
header h1.display-4{
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
```

Read more about [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I tried the third one you suggested other property, for example, background-size worked but font-size 2em doesn't work. I guess 2em is still big enough for small device like iphone5/iphone5s(I testes on chrome)

Comment: @loone96 Use `!important` with `font-size` like `font-size: 2em !important;` i am sure its been target with high precedence selector , and also you are right `2em` is so big on mobile devices lowers its value like `1.2em` or `14px`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask you one more question? If I want to select h4 tag in <section><div><h4></h4></div></section>, is this correct to write section>div>h4{} in CSS?

Comment: @loone96 Glad to hear that helps...  Yes its correct Css selector, but i wolud suggest you to use at least one class and then make selection so that it wont effect when ever you use same htnl structure like section div h4 in any other page ... And also this >  means direct in terms of CSS you can readmore about this in above mention link

Answer (score 1):

The selector `#headerh1 {...}` should be `header h1 {...}` (no ID but tag, space between `header` and `h1`)

If that doesn't select the element, there is another more specific css rule in your code, so you'll have to increase css specifity, for example by writing (note the spaces and "not-spaces"...):

```
header.text-white div.jumbotron.bgimg.text-white h1.display-4 { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe try adding an `id` to the header :)

```
<header id="headerh1" class="text-white">
```